# How can I detect the operating system using GWT?

Tags: macos, gwt, operating-system, keyboard-shortcuts

Basically what I want to know is to find out if my GWT application is running on a MacOS or any other operating system, to setup the shortcuts properly using <kbd>cmd</kbd> on a MacOS and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> everywhere else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Navigator;
...

String platform = Navigator.getPlatform();
```

This returns a String (the same as JavaScript's `navigator.platform`). You can then decide on the OS similar to [this script](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html): It simply checks for the substring "Win"/"Mac"/"iPhone"/"Linux".