# Detect 64-bit or 32-bit Windows from Google Web Toolkit

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, gxt

How can I detect the OS version (32-bit or 64-bit) in `Google Web Toolkit`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect the operating system using GWT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372443/how-can-i-detect-the-operating-system-using-gwt)

Comment: If you can elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish, that will help others to give you better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Window.Navigator getUserAgent()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Navigator.html#getUserAgent--) method. That string will have some clue as to the OS. Here are some examples for various browsers:

Chrome: "Mozilla/5.0 (**Windows** NT 10.0; **Win64**; **x64**) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"

Firefox: Mozilla/5.0 (**Windows** NT 10.0; **WOW64**; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0

IE11: "Mozilla/5.0 (**Windows** NT 10.0; **WOW64**; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

Edge: Mozilla/5.0 (**Windows** NT 10.0; **Win64**; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393

All of the have Windows in the name, and either Win64 or WOW64. The latter means a 32 bit browser running on a 64 bit Windows OS.

```
public boolean isWindows(){
  return Window.Navigator.getUserAgent().indexOf('Windows') != -1;
}

public boolean isWin64(){
  return isWindows() && (
    Window.Navigator.getUserAgent().indexOf('Win64') != -1 ||
    Window.Navigator.getUserAgent().indexOf('WOW64') != -1);
}
```

It is usually a bad idea to query for OS, but there are some valid use cases, for example to offer a user the correct download for their platform.